# Uncaught ReferenceError: sapper is not defined, in main.js Svelte file

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I have done the following:

- installed

  - node.js
  - Svelte
  - Sapper
- created

  - client.js
  - server.js

This is my main.js:

```
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: 'Acme Limited'
    }
});

export default app;
```

client.js:

```
import * as sapper from '@sapper/app';

sapper.start({
    target: document.querySelector('#sapper')
});
```

Top of App.svelte:

```
<script>
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
  import * as sapper from '@sapper/app';
```

My app was working until I added Sapper.

I tried adding this line to main.js:

```
import * as sapper from '@sapper/app';
```

The only code of mine that references is Sapper is in the index file:

```
<!-- src/routes/index.svelte -->
<svelte:head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</svelte:head>

<h1>Hello, and welcome!</h1>

<nav>
    <a href=".">Home</a>
    <a href="about">About</a>
</nav>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The error in your title doesn't seem to match the code in your question. To get that error, you would expect to see the `sapper` symbol _somewhere_ in `main.js`. Can you please provide the error message in full, including line numbers, filenames, etc. A screenshot of the error might also provide some context

Comment: It's on line number 8.There's only one main.js in my project, at least that I aware of.

Comment: That doesn't really address my comment. As another old adage goes... _"help me help you"_

Comment: Fair enough, but in the title I said "in main.js". The context is running Svelte.

Comment: Sorry to get annoyed, but these configuration things are not my bag. I'm a Mathematician come Business man, not a Computer Science major.

Comment: Screenshot added!

Comment: Can you add the contents of your App.svelte file please? It seems likely that that component is what is using sapper, and likely has a missing import or reference.

Comment: Top of that file added! Also a comment about Sapper at the end of the question.

Comment: I think I'll knock Sapper on the head for now svelte-routes looks easier to use.

Comment: Not a bad idea. One last suggestion I was going to make was to check your webpack config to ensure that the '@' was set to resolve to the correct location, as it sounds like your import is failing. Switching to another routing provider would likely get you around the issue as well, though. Good luck!